# Rails, duplicate code refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

How can I refactor this similar snippets of code in rails controller?

app/controllers/albums_controller.rb:58…62 < >

```
def set_album
  if current_user.admin?
    @album = User.find(params[:user_id]).albums.find(params[:id])
  else
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:45…49 < >

```
def set_article
  if current_user.admin?
    @article = User.find(params[:user_id]).articles.find(params[:id])
  else
    @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:55…59 < >

```
def set_photo
  if current_user.admin?
    @photo = User.find(params[:user_id]).photos.find(params[:id])
  else
    @photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controllers/concerns/user_resource.rb

```
module UserResource
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_resource , only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  end

  def set_resource
    association = controller_name.classify.downcase
    resource = current_user.admin? ? User.find(params[:user_id]) : current_user
    resource = resource.send(association.to_s.pluralize).find(params[:id])
    instance_variable_set("@#{association}", resource)
  end

  def correct_user
    association = controller_name.classify.downcase
    redirect_to root_path unless admin_or_current?(instance_variable_get("@#{association}").user)
  end
end
```

then, in {photos, albums, articles}_controller.rb

```
include UserResource
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a new controller:

```
class ResourceController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_resource, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  private

  def set_resource
    user = current_user.admin? ? User.find(params[:user_id]) : current_user
    resource = user.send(controller_name.to_sym).find(params[:id])
    instance_variable_set("@#{controller_name.singularize}", resource)
  end
end
```

then your albums_controller.rb:

```
class AlbumsController < ResourceController
  # use @album in show, edit, update, and destroy
end
```

articles_controller.rb:

```
class ArticlesController < ResourceController
  # use @article in show, edit, update, and destroy    
end
```

photos_controller.rb:

```
class PhotosController < ResourceController
  # use @photo in show, edit, update, and destroy
end
```

Comment: Yes, fine! But I've created controller concern and include it in all "resource" controllers. It similar method. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

It would a good idea to use metaprogramming here, I mean something like:

```
def set_resource(association_singular) # e.g. :photo
  resource = current_user.admin? ? User.find(params[:user_id]) : current_user
  resource = resource.send(association.to_s.pluralize).find(params[:id]) )
  instance_variable_set("@#{association}", resource)
end
```

Then, within a controller either `before_filter only: [:action]` or

```
def action
  # ...
  set_resource(:photo)
  # ...
end
```